# passing pointers (the name of array) into function in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Lets say we create an array like:

```
int a[4]={1,2,3,4};
```

Now `a` is the name of this array and also the pointer points to the first element `a[0]`. So when I want to call the elements in the array, I can use `a[ i ]` or `*(a+i)`.

Now I have a function:

```
void print_array(int* array, int arraySize){
    for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
       cout<<*(array+i)<<endl;
       cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I pass `a[4]={1,2,3,4}` into this function using `print_array(a,4)`, for the first line of `cout`, I fully understand because I use `*(a+i)` method to access data and `a` is the pointer I passed.

What I can't understand is: since I pass a pointer `a` into function, why can I use `a` in the format of `a[i]` like the second line of `cout`? Isn't `a` a pointer? If `a` is a pointer why does `a[i]` work?

This has confused me for a whole day. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: a[b] is always exactly identical to `*(a+b)` regardless of what a and b are.

Comment: @fuz explained in detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a?rq=1

Comment: I think a[i] will essentially translate to the value at a plus one size of what a points to.

Comment: @i can't agree with your pluses one comment because b will typically be an integer and is incremented by one however the address is incremented by b*size of the type of array. Disregard this comment if I miss some obvious aspect of c++.

Comment: @marshalcraft The pointer already knows the size. `int* a = ...; int* b = a+1` will result in a difference of `sizeof(int)` between the values of `a`and `b`. Using `char* a = ...; char* b = a+1` the addresses will only differ by `sizeof(char)`

Comment: Oh and because `a[b]` is equivalent `*(a+b)` this again is equivalent to `*(b+a)` and `b[a]`. Allowing you to write `0[a]` instead of `a[0]`: https://godbolt.org/g/fk0hdR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is an array, not a pointer.   They are not the same things.   However, the name `a` can be implicitly converted to a pointer (with the value `&a[0]`).

For example;

```
  int main()
  {
       int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
       int *p = a;              //  p now has the value &a[0]
```

Now, after this partial code snippet, assuming `i` is an integral value,  rules of the language amount to;

- `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)` which is equivalent to `*(&a[0] + i)`
- `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p + i)`

Now, since `p` is equal to `&a[0]` this means that `a[i]`, `*(a + i)`, `p[i]`, and `*(p + i)` are all equivalent.

When calling `print_arrat(a, 4)` where `a` is the name of an array, then `a` is ALWAYS converted to a pointer.   This means `print_arrat()` is always passed a pointer.    And this means `*(array + i)` inside `print_arrat()` is the same as `a[i]` in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Because in effect, while the subscript operator is defined on arrays, what happens is that they decay into pointers for the arithmetic to occur.

Meaning if `a` is an array, semantically what happens is:

`int b = a[i]; => int *__tmp = a; int b = *(__tmp + i);`

However, once operator overloading comes into play, then it is no longer true that `a[i] == *(a + i)`. The right hand side may not even be defined.

Comment: That's true in C and in C++ before [CWG 1213](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213), but now in C++ `a[i]` and `*(a+i)` have subtle differences when `a` has array type.

Comment: This is a very straight way of thinking(it helps explaining a lot). But I wonder is it defined like that in the standard? (c and c++ if possible?). Because I always thought of this as a array feature that extends to pointers (as the declaration of arrays uses the same brackets)

Comment: @cpplearner - That question was tagged C originally, where what I said does hold. Whatever. I'll chalk it up to the OP being a new user.

Comment: @cpplearner - Wait, CWG 1213 added that to make the value categories of the expression clearer. The decay **must still happen**. Because it's equivalent to `*(a + i)` by the standard, and arithmetic **is not** defined for arrays, only pointers.

Comment: @StoryTeller By "that" I mean "you can't in fact use the subscript operator on arrays".

Comment: What CWG 1213 affects is whether `a[i]` (or `*(a+i)`) is an xvalue or lvalue - which (subtly) restricts how they can be used.   It doesn't change their equivalence (i.e. `a[i] == *(a + i)` will still test true).

Answer (score 0):

This quote from the C++ Standard will make the point clear (5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postﬁx expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
>   a postﬁx expression. **One of the expressions shall have the type
>   “array of T” or “pointer to T”** and the other shall have unscoped
>   enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T”
>   shall be a completely-deﬁned object type.64 The expression E1[E2] is
>   identical (by deﬁnition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for
>   details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. —end note], except
>   that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that
>   operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> What I can't understand is: since I pass a pointer "a" into function, why can I use "a" in the format of a[i] like the second line of "cout"?

Because subscript operator `a[i]` is defined for arrays and it is equivalent to `*(a+i)` by definition.

In the line with `cout`, you use `array[i]` however, where `array` is a pointer. This is also allowed, because the subscript operator is also defined for pointers.

> Isn't "a" a pointer?

No. `a` is an array. `array` is a pointer.